# Зачем восстановили ответ-дубль?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, удаление-ответов, модераторский-произвол, восстановление-сообщений

Есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1505060/532877). Является дублем другого (только в отличие от оригинала дубль плохо оформлен).

Ответ был рекомендован на удаление в очереди проверок, под ним оставлен комментарий "такой ответ уже есть", получивший 3 голоса. Модератор удалил ответ. А другой модератор зачем-то восстановил.

Вопрос: зачем приносить мусор обратно, который только что был выкинут?

Скрин дубля и оригинала:

[image: дубль и оригинал]

История ответа:

[image: Скрин истории ответа]

Comment: Не совсем дубли же, во втором есть упоминание, что это векторное и псевдоскалярное произведение. Хотя все равно надо снести, ибо спам Киберфорума.

Comment: Первый ответ судя по всему тоже оттуда.